# How to add custom internet headers to emails?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsto, outlook-addin

Can someone provide how to create and add custom internet headers to the mailItem and how to read them later? I am trying to attach a keyword to every email that is sent so it can be read by another outlook client with the same add-in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're writing a Outlook Plugin (based on your tag).  Get a Handle on your current mail item (email in draft form)...

```
// Describes your Custom Header
string  PS_INTERNET_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/Custom-Property-Name";

// Sets Your Custom Header
CurrentMailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(PS_INTERNET_HEADERS, "ValueOfCustomProperty" );

// Reads Your Custom Header
string valueResult = CurrentMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PS_INTERNET_HEADERS);
```

You might get away something like this:

```
// Sets Your Custom Header
CurrentMailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("CustomHeaderName", "ValueOfCustomProperty" );

// Reads Your Custom Header
string valueResult = CurrentMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("CustomHeaderName");
```

Also, check out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b4218b03-d495-459f-a112-8d4e1e05ad3e/set-custom-headers-to-outlook-mailitem?forum=outlookdev

Comment: Let me know if this helped or not.

Comment: Is there a way to properly check if the Custom Header has been set, in case when an email does not have the property set. `string valueResult = CurrentMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PS_INTERNET_HEADERS);` return a Null and `if(CurrentMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PS_INTERNET_HEADERS != null);` also does not work.

Comment: For as good as Microsoft's documentation is around VSTO development, it's really surprising to me that adding custom email headers is kept such a secret. I found some official documentation that references that wacky schema URI you listed, but it's marked as obsolete. Doesn't exactly inspire confidence that this approach will be supported in the long term.

Comment: @hcd00045, would you be willing to share the reference you mention?

Comment: @SpencerWilliamson -- oh goodness, that was a couple of years ago. I will have a look around but I'm not too optimistic I'll find it. :-/