# Outlook drag-and-drop: how to get 'Internet Headers' from message

Tags: c#, vba, vb.net, outlook, exchange-server

Frequently undesirable messages are received even after any good spam/virus filter.

As a secondary wall, we suggest our user to check the suspicious message properties ('internet headers') to verify the real origin. This action, for the non-tech guys is not easy.

I wrote a simple application to drag the message into it and analyze the headers locating IP addresses and origin: obviously, if the message is from your mother, you know she is not in China...

How can we get the 'internet headers' from the message? Is there any hidden property there?

```
Private Sub MainForm_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim myExp As Outlook.Explorer = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer
    Dim myMailItem As Outlook.MailItem = DirectCast(myExp.Selection.Item(1), Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim x = myMailItem.Body
    myExp = Nothing
    myMailItem = Nothing
    myOlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This works fine to get the body and other data like To, From etc, however no property expose 'Internet Headers'.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133383/how-to-add-custom-internet-headers-to-emails

Comment: That link is for **adding** new MIME header, not retrieving the existing headers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` MAPI property:

```
Dim headers As String = myMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F")
```

Comment: Some messages if internal to internal never go out to the Internet thus no internet headers.

Comment: Yes, but the OP specifically asks for the internet (MIME) headers.

Comment: Even if there are internet headers, if you subscribe to office 365 hosted exchange you actually can't trace back to any meaningful IPs because they all belong to Microsoft Azure internally. I can't submit to realtime blacklists like spamcop for any spam sent to our work email for this reason. The answer is correct but in practice there are many situations where it is not usable/useful.

Comment: Office 365 is not widely used by spammers - it is not free, and the users must supply authentication information that can be traced back to them, such as a phone number.

Comment: No I just mean the spam that doesn't get stopped by Microsoft that passes for good can not be reported as spam to real time blacklists directly.